# How to classify the numbers by value in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With:

```
import pandas as pd     
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,12,14,121,131,298,299,1001]})
print df.a.mean()
```

returns an average of all the numbers:

```
157.583333333
```

Half of the numbers are smaller than 100. I wonder if there is a way to break the numbers into the categories (essentially classifying them). I would specify the number of groups to classify the numbers into and the function would return a list where each number is replaced with the corresponding category's index. So the numbers smaller then 100 would be given an integer category 1. Then the numbers from 100 - 200 would be given a category 2 and etc. Essentially some kind of rounding function that would round the numbers to that all into the range of values: from 0 to 100, from 100.1 to 200.0 and etc

Comment: "where each number is replaced with the corresponding category's index". Or just add a column 'category' to the dataframe? Then you won't lose the input numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd     
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,12,14,121,131,298,299,1001]})
df['category'] = df['a'] // 100 + 1
print(df[['a', 'category']])

       a  category
0      1         1
1      2         1
2      3         1
3      4         1
4      5         1
5     12         1
6     14         1
7    121         2
8    131         2
9    298         3
10   299         3
11  1001        11
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.cut`. the `bins=` argument allows you to define the number of categories to get. The result is a series with bin ranges:

```
pd.cut(df.a, bins=10)
Out[156]: 
0        (0, 101]
1        (0, 101]
2        (0, 101]
3        (0, 101]
4        (0, 101]
5        (0, 101]
6        (0, 101]
7      (101, 201]
8      (101, 201]
9      (201, 301]
10     (201, 301]
11    (901, 1001]
Name: a, dtype: category
Categories (10, object): [(0, 101] < (101, 201] < (201, 301] < (301, 401] ... (601, 701] < (701, 801] < (801, 901] < (901, 1001]]
```

Comment: How does one use this if the *number* of bins is unknown, but the size of the bin (all equal) is set?

Comment: By size of the bin you mean the number of elements you want to get in each bin, or the width of each bin range? Not sure to catch what actual case you have in mind

Comment: The bin width. The question suggests a fixed bin width of 100, hence my question.

Comment: You don't, pd.cut is number of bins oriented. It matches the first part of the somehow incoherent question of OP: I addressed the "I would specify the number of groups to classify the numbers" part of the question, and you addressed "100 would be given an integer category 1. Then the numbers from 100 - 200 would be given a category 2 and etc. ". As you are asking above, you can't define both as these variables are related.

Comment: BTW to get a similar result, you can add the argument labels=False , but again, it's number of bins oriented so the cuts are still done around min and max values divided into the number of bins you asked for. So with pd.cut you will get category = 10 for the last record, and not 11. Depends at the end what you want to achieve. Fixed width/size is addressed by integer-division, fixed bins by pd.cut

Comment: Just for reference, you can use a list to define where the bins will be cut and the labels to determine what actual labels to use. For instance, if you want to divide numbers from 0 to 10 into bins of width 2 you can write
`pd.cut(values, bins=[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10], labels=[1, 3, 5, 7, 9])`